# Can't use '-' character in a Java regular expression, it doesn't find the pattern in the given text

Tags: java, regex

It is my first time I'm using regular expressions and I have some problems.

I'm writing a simple compiler program, and now I'm working on a "parsing" module which takes some assembler line and splits it to parts.

Some part of the line may consist of one of those expressions:

```
String comp = "[(0)(1)(-1)(D)(A)(!D)(!A)(-D)(-A)(D+1)(A+1)(D-1)(A-1)(D+A)(D-A)(A-D)(D&A)(D|A)(M)(M+1)(M-1)(D+M)(D-M)(M-D)(D&M)(D|M)]";
```

So for now on I just want to see which expression matches the following regular expression, because that's what I need for now.

Java compiler doesn't compile such an expression and writes that:

> Illegal character range near index 46
>   [(0)(1)(-1)(D)(A)(!D)(!A)(-D)(-A)(D+1)(A+1)(D-1)(A-1)(D+A)(D-A)(A-D)(D&A)(D|A)(M)(M+1)(M-1)(D+M)(D-M)(M-D)(D&M)(D|M)]

I tried to do it like that:

```
    String comp = "[(0)(1)(\\-1)(D)(A)(!D)(!A)(\\-D)(\\-A)(D+1)(A+1)(D\\-1)(A\\-1)(D+A)(D\\-A)(A-D)(D&A)(D|A)(M)(M+1)(M\\-1)(D+M)(D\\-M)(M\\-D)(D&M)(D|M)]";
```

That makes the program compile, but it find a match for strings like "D" or "1" but not for "D+1" or "D-1", what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What text do you **plan** to match with that? Could you give use examples? Your entire regex is a big character class which is **almost certainly** not what you want.

Comment: You certainly meant "0|1|-1|D|A ....."

Answer (score 3):

When you wrap square brackets around (a part of) your regex, it becomes a character set (or character class). A character set always matches just one character. So your regex:

```
[(0)(1)(-1)(D)(A)(!D)(!A)(-D)(-A)(D+1)(A+1)(D-1)(A-1)(D+A)(D-A)(A-D)(D&A)(D|A)(M)(M+1)(M-1)(D+M)(D-M)(M-D)(D&M)(D|M)]
```

matches just one of:

```
'(', '0', ')', '1', '-', ... , '+', ...
```

Also notice that meta characters like `(`, `)` and `+` have no special meaning inside character sets. A character set has its own meta characters, like `-`, which is used to denote a range. For example, `[a-c]` matches either `a`, `b` or `c`.

That is why you can't use the `-` in your regex, which shouldn't be a character set, of course.

More info about character sets: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you cannot use multiple characters inside a () inside a [] this way. It appears to turn the string in () into individual characters.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    test("[(C)(D1)]", "D"); // true!
    test("[(D)(D1)]", "D1");
    test("((D)|(D1))", "D1");
    test("[(D)(D+1)]", "D+1"); // false
    test("[(D)(D+1)]", "+"); // true!
    test("[(D)(D\\+1)]", "D+1");
    test("((D)|(D\\+1))", "D+1");
}

private static void test(String regex, String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^"+regex+"$");
    System.out.println(regex +" matches "+text+" is " + pattern.matcher(text).find()) ;
}
```

prints

```
[(C)(D1)] matches D is true
[(D)(D1)] matches D1 is false
((D)|(D1)) matches D1 is true
[(D)(D+1)] matches D+1 is false
[(D)(D+1)] matches + is true
[(D)(D\+1)] matches D+1 is false
((D)|(D\+1)) matches D+1 is true
```

Comment: Since his entire regex is one big character group, only the `-` has a special meaning in there.

Comment: Peter, character sets (or character classes) are a small language inside regex itself. A character set has its own meta-characters, and the "normal" meta characters have no special meaning in them.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, can you give an example of what you mean? Not sure I get your point.

Comment: @Joachim, you're right (of course), but the term "character group" might be a bit confusing since it's not grouping anything (in the sense of match-groups). I'd stick with "character class" or "character set".

Comment: +1 @Bart Kiers, I see now. I was thinking of Charset as a character set.  This is a good explaination of why what I found does what it does.